# JBrowserDriver Exception

Tags: java, headless-browser

.I have been developing a web crawler and I just want to implement JBroserDriver into my project.

[JBrowserDriver](https://github.com/MachinePublishers/jBrowserDriver)

When I create an insance of JBroserDriver I have faced an exception like that:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Could not launch browser.

Driver info: driver.version: JBrowserDriver

at com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.Util.handleException(Util.java:140) ~[jbrowserdriver-0.16.3.jar:?]

at com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.JBrowserDriver.(JBrowserDriver.java:282) ~[jbrowserdriver-0.16.3.jar:?]

Here is my code block

```
                linkedHashMap.put("Host", "dynamic_header");
                linkedHashMap.put("Connection", "keep-alive");
                linkedHashMap.put("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
                linkedHashMap.put("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
                linkedHashMap.put("User-Agent", "dynamic_header");
                linkedHashMap.put("Referer", "dynamic_header");
                linkedHashMap.put("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
                linkedHashMap.put("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
                linkedHashMap.put("Cookie", "dynamic_header");

                RequestHeaders requestHeaders = new RequestHeaders(linkedHashMap);

                Settings.Builder builder = Settings.builder().requestHeaders(requestHeaders);

                builder.ajaxWait(AppConstants.getJavascriptAjaxRuntime());

                builder.logJavascript(true);
                builder.logTrace(true);

                **driver = new JBrowserDriver(builder.build());**
```

Do you have any idea aboyt the solution?
Thanks